# Converting Running Columns Into Rows

Tags: excel

Limited experience with Excel. My highest grasp is concatenating cells.

I have a dataset that is split into two columns with each column consisting of a user's photo, name, address, and join date, followed by the next user.

Some pages of this spreadsheet contain thousands of users.

Looking for a formula that will convert both columns into single rows for each user. So instead of:

```
A A
B B
C C
D D
E E
A A
B B
C C
D D
E E
```

I want

```
A B C D E
A B C D E
A B C D E
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is `aa` `bb` and not `a` `b`. Maybe post a screenshot for clarity.

Comment: @Jsleshem the latter is correct. Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the conventions for illustrating problems on this forum.

Comment: How do you get from the AA/BB/CC/DD/EE/AA/BB/CC/DD/EE to ABCDE/ABCDE/ABCDE  What is a user in this fakey/example data? It's very very difficult to understand what you are wanting. Can you use sample data that isn't letters to better illustrate what you are trying to do? Your current sample data has 20 letters, but your output only has 15 letters. Where did the other 5 go?

Comment: @user8303910 can you please post post screen shots? This is too hard to answer how you phrased it.